# Dynamic data on overlay layer in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I am using openlayers to visualize an industry using image as the layer. On the raster layer I have created an overlay layer.Is it possible to show updated values (dynamic runtime values - as integer) in the overlay layer that gets updated every second? If so please help me how to get this done in openlayers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with features on a vector layer. Provide a datasource that has features on the same coordinates than your features on the raster layer.
Then you can access the attributes of these features. For example, population:

```
myvectorlayer.features[myfeatureindex].attributes.population = 10000;
```

(or use one of the myvectorlayer.getFeature* functions)

From now on, you can add a label for the features with [Openlayers.Style](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html) :

```
var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
  'label' : '${population}',
  'fontSize' : '8px',
  'fontColor' : 'white',
  'labelOutlineColor' : "#000000", 
  'labelOutlineWidth' : 2});
```

Where ${population} is the attributes name on the vector layers features.